# How does order by clause works if two values are equal?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-order-by

This is my NEWSPAPER table.

```
    National News   A   1
    Sports          D   1
    Editorials      A   12
    Business        E   1
    Weather         C   2
    Television      B   7
    Births          F   7
    Classified      F   8
    Modern Life     B   1
    Comics          C   4
    Movies          B   4
    Bridge          B   2
    Obituaries      F   6
    Doctor Is In    F   6
```

When i run this query

```
select feature,section,page from NEWSPAPER
where section = 'F'
order by page;
```

It gives this output

```
Doctor Is In    F   6
Obituaries      F   6
Births          F   7
Classified      F   8
```

But in Kevin Loney's Oracle 10g Complete Reference the output is like this

```
Obituaries      F   6
Doctor Is In    F   6
Births          F   7
Classified      F   8
```

Please help me understand how is it happening?

Comment: Aren't they the same output?  At any rate, the order for results with the same value is undefined, and probably comes back based on how they happen to be stored on the disk.

Comment: Oh sorry was unable to copy the output from book properly. Added the output from the book correctly.

Comment: @mellamokb-how they happen to be stored on disk? Is it in order they are inserted into table or based on the OS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In relational databases, tables are sets and are unordered.  The `order by` clause is used primarily for output purposes (and a few other cases such as a subquery containing `rownum`).

This is a good place to start.  The SQL standard does not specify what has to happen when the keys on an `order by` are the same.  And this is for good reason.  Different techniques can be used for sorting.  Some might be stable (preserving original order).  Some methods might not be.

Focus on whether the same rows are in the sets, not their ordering.  By the way, I would consider this an unfortunate example.  The book should not have ambiguous sorts in its examples.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar . . . What I mean is that the standard allows the database vendors leeway on how to implement certain things, and this is a good thing.

Comment: To expand, ordering can be processing intensive: not specifying a default ordering leaves vendors free to optimize queries that do not have an ORDER BY clause however they see fit.

Answer (score 14):

If you need *reliable, reproducible* ordering to occur when two values in your `ORDER BY` clause's first column are the same, you should always provide another, secondary column to also order on. While you might be able to assume that they will sort themselves based on order entered (almost always the case to my knowledge, but be aware that the SQL standard does not specify any form of default ordering) or index, you never should (unless it is specifically documented as such for the engine you are using--and even then I'd personally never rely on that).

Your query, if you wanted alphabetical sorting by feature within each page, should be:

```sql
SELECT feature,section,page FROM NEWSPAPER
WHERE section = 'F'
ORDER BY page, feature;
```

Comment: @taswyn- this is exactly the next example says. But i was wondering why i got different output compared to the book? Wanted to know about if there is any default way to handle.

Comment: Even if you considered the order entered by to be a default ordering, you should rely on your own programmed logic rather than taking a shortcut which could result in situations you had not forseen. The SQL standard does not specify default ordering. To my knowledge Oracle does not document a default ordering, which means anything you rely on because you seem to get reproducible results now could change. Any results you want to see reliably should always be represented by your program logic. Don't make assumptions about anything not specifically defined by your tools or your code.

Comment: do you have any idea which column will get higher preference while ordering result-set. I am working on some ranking stuff based on a column which stores scores, but the problem is that multiple rows have got same score values and when i fetch them they come in random order. if I will use primary key of int type as second sorting argument will it always give me result in same order.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `SELECT` statement to query data from a table, the order which rows appear in the result set may not be what you expected.

In some cases, the rows that appear in the result set are in the order that they are stored in the table physically. However, in case the query optimizer uses an index to process the query, the rows will appear as they are stored in the index key order. For this reason, the order of rows in the result set is undetermined or unpredictable.

> The query optimizer is a built-in software component in the database
> system that determines the most efficient way for an SQL statement to
> query the requested data.