# Defined SQL behavior when ordering by values with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am paging through a very large result set with page size of 5000 and ordering by a last updated date time. I am also selecting all records with a last updated time less than the start of the operation.

Everything is working correctly however I will occasionally see records more than a single time. I was wondering what the defined behavior is when a ordered column shares the same value.

For instance if I order by column X and three rows have a value of 5 for that column. Will those values **always** be in the same order using the same order by expression?

Comment: According to [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058045/how-does-order-by-clause-works-if-two-values-are-equal) the SQL standard does not specify whether values will always be in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the same order will always be applied.

If there are no column used in `ORDER BY`, then the result will be random. You might observe repeatable results (meaning the same order for several runs), but you cannot depend on it to be always true. You may want to add another column in the `ORDER BY` to get consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same concept as a primary key.. You need to be able to uniquely identify the data so the program has no choice but to return the data the same way.. Consider adding another column to your `ORDER BY` statement and use `ASC` or `DESC` to make sure it prints out the same way.