# ActiveRecord limit method does not seem to respect order of relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I think I may have uncovered a bug with `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation#limit` but I'm not sure and wanted to see if there is a simpler explanation. I'm running Rails 5.0.2.

Assume the following models:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
    attr_accessor :engagement
end
```

I will first select all my contacts using this query:

```
contacts = Company.last.contacts.order(engagement: :desc)
```

This outputs the following SQL:

```
Company Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY "companies"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Contact Load (36.9ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."company_id" = 94 ORDER BY "contacts"."engagement" DESC
```

So far so good. Now lets assume I want to grab an array of ids from the first 20 contacts in the relation. I would expect the order of the ids in the returned array to match the order in which they appear in the relation.

First I will use `pluck(:id)[0..19]`. This returns the following:

```
contacts.pluck(:id)[0..19]
#=> [861, 862, 802, 868, 794, 1583, 1267, 1857, 1081, 1686, 1041, 1535, 1560, 1707, 1770, 1600, 1205, 2027, 1179, 1184]
```

Next I try `map(&:id)[0..19]`, which unsurprisingly returns the same result:

```
contacts.map(&:id)[0..19]
#=> [861, 862, 802, 868, 794, 1583, 1267, 1857, 1081, 1686, 1041, 1535, 1560, 1707, 1770, 1600, 1205, 2027, 1179, 1184]
```

Finally I try `limit(20).pluck(:id)`, which returns an unexpected result:

```
contacts.limit(20).pluck(:id)
(4.5ms)  SELECT  "contacts"."id" FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."company_id" = 94 ORDER BY "contacts"."engagement" DESC LIMIT 20
#=> [861, 862, 802, 868, 794, 1686, 1081, 1857, 1267, 1600, 1583, 1357, 1560, 1041, 1535, 1201, 1707, 1770, 2075, 1937]
```

Notice that in the first two arrays, the ids are in the same order, but when I use `limit`, they appear out of order, even though the SQL generated clearly includes an `ORDER BY` clause.

What's interesting to note is that the order of the ids is always correct for the first few contacts where `engagement > 0.0`. Once the values for `engagement` become `0.0`, the ordering starts to vary. For example, here is what the engagement numbers are for those same 20 contacts:

```
[56.0, 44.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out in comments, the problem is that when [`order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) meets two objects with identical `engagement` values it "sorts" it in some specific way.

What could help is passing an additional parameter to the `ORDER` clause (for example `id`):

```
Company.last.contacts.order(engagement: :desc, id: :asc)
```

Comment: When I tried that I got: `[861, 862, 802, 868, 794, 1686, 1081, 1857, 1267, 1600, 1583, 1357, 1560, 1041, 1535, 1201, 1707, 1770, 2075, 1937]`. It could very well be that `pluck` doesn't respect the order, but than `map` must also not respect the order since the results from `map` and `pluck` were identical.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH `pluck` and `map` work on different levels: pluck goes to DB, whereas `map` operates in memory on the collection returned by `contacts.limit(20)`. But my guess is wrong, as I see the result is the same.

Comment: What's interesting is that for all examples, the first few ids are indeed in the correct order. It's only once the values for `engagement` become `0.0` that the ordering starts to vary.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH oooh, you are on the correct path! Edit the question with this information, it 100% has to do with that!

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH you might add additional argument to order, so that it takes over, when `engagement` starts to be identical (`0.0`). For example, `.order(engagement: :desc, id: :asc)`

Comment: That solved the problem! Could it be that `pluck` and `map` both ignore the ordering when the attributes ordered by are equal?

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH yea, it has something to do with the fact that DB takes care of ordering objects with identical values, but I can't tell you what exactly it is. So neither `pluck` nor `map` is the problem here, it is `order` :)

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I can trust any of my ordered queries to truly be in the correct order unless I always apply a secondary fallback order such as `id: :asc`. That just seems to verbose and against the spirit of what Rails is all about...

Comment: Can you edit your answer to summarize this so I can tag it is the right answer?

Comment: On the other hand, when you have "enough" fallback order args, you can sleep peacefully :)

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH actually just did :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just the order in which the database chooses to return the results. In SQL, there is no guarantee on the ordering, unless you specify an `order by`. Even when specified, I believe that within a block of identically ordered results (i.e. `0.0` in this case), there is again no guarantee on the ordering of the results - it can be in whatever ordering the database deems most appropriate and/or efficient for that particular query.

If you need the results back in a specific order, then it's best to add it as an additional `order by` argument (`id` in this case)

---

Edit: Here's a bit more discussion on the topic: [How does order by clause works if two values are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058045/how-does-order-by-clause-works-if-two-values-are-equal)

It's quite possible here that `SELECT  "contacts"."id"` and `SELECT  "contacts".*` use different indexes, which results in the difference in ordering.