# How order by fetch if column has same values

Tags: sql-order-by, multiple-columns

[image]

How a order by clause in oracle fetches the records, if the order by clause columns has same values.

select * from hk order by item,units
--item,units have same values for deal_id 1,2.
Please suggest on what basis will extract the two records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL documentation does not specify any technique for sorting the rows when the values in the columns are the same. This is because the techniques implemented for sorting rows are different.
You could refer to the question below to understand more.

[How does order by clause works if two values are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058045/how-does-order-by-clause-works-if-two-values-are-equal)

Comment: @Harish Hope this answer cleared all your doubts. If this answer helped you then you can mark it as correct, clicking on the huge tickmark at the left side of this answer. This will help other users to find the correct answer easily.